# How to resolve the error user realm discovery failed with Azure AD

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, entra-id

I am trying to install Azure AD Connect in my server2012 R2 Server. I have followed the Custom installation option provided with the installer. I have followed the document from Microsoft docs. 
[Microsoft doc AAD custom install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom)

But I am getting error as  An erroroccured executing  Configure AD Sync task:user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed. 
No specific  information for this failure is available.

I have tried Express settings too , but again same error is occurring. 
Expect help to resolve  this error . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

User Realm Discovery Failed: **Network or proxy configuration issues**. The network cannot be reached. See [Troubleshoot connectivity issues in the installation wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-troubleshoot-connectivity#troubleshoot-connectivity-issues-in-the-installation-wizard).

Here a [case](https://tarekeltouny.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/getting-the-user-realm-discovery-failed-error-with-microsoft-azure-ad-connect-tool/) same as you, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

i did changes in web config it it works

```
<system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```

just updated targetframework